# Inequality for Difference Between Two Harmonic Numbers

Tags: inequality, logarithms, harmonic-numbers

I want to know if the following inequality holds: $H_n-H_k \leq \log{n}-\log{k}$ where $k \leq n$ and $n \to \infty$.

I have seen two similar questions such as [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102197/difference-between-harmonic-numbers) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633913/difference-between-two-harmonic-numbers-when-n-is-not-infinite) but I could not verify if my statement is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$H_n-H_k=\sum_{j=k+1}^n\frac 1j\le\int_{k}^{n}\frac{dt}t=\log\frac nk$$